# Question related to Process builder field update based on conditions

Tags: process-builder, if

I am working on a scenario where we have a custom object which has standard Name field and an Autonumber field and 3 record types. I am trying to update the Name field based on the record type as below:

If record type is A then update Name field as Name = 'A-'+ AutonumberField__c
If record type is B then update Name field as Name = 'B-'+ AutonumberField__c
If record type is C then update Name field as Name = 'C-'+ AutonumberField__c

I was trying the following in the process builder below but not sure of the exact syntax:

```
     (             
        IF( [CustomObject__c].RecordType.Name, 'A',  
              [CustomObject__c].Name ='A'+[CustomObject__c].Name+AutoNumField__c)
     )
```

The conditions can be easily written if a Trigger is used but facing trouble in building the conditions in the process builder.

Comment: your text problem description states you are smashing the Name field to be recTypeName+AutoNumber but your code has you appending the autonumber to the name field. which is it?

Comment: @cropredy, Please ignore my code, I was trying something which was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula to set the custom object's name is simply:

```
[CustomObject__c].RecordType.Name & '-' & [CustomObject__c].AutoNumberField__c
```